# Jenkins Pipeline best way to use choice parameter for checking conditions

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

Pipeline executes two jobs : `Job X` and `Job Y`.
The Pipeline has a choice parameter which is required by `Job Y`.
Choice parameter options: `A`,`B` and `C`.

`Job Y` has 3 conditions :

`if Choice==A` then do `task 1`

`else if Choice==B` then do `task 2`

`else` do `task 3`

Getting stuck at declaring choice conditions at STAGE of `Job Y`.

p.s. tried Active Choice parameter, can't work through it.

Can anybody help out with the logic for this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming that Job Y is called from your pipeline as a downstream job. Thus somewhere, (probably the end of your pipeline) you will have:

`build job: 'CloudbeeFolder1/Path/To/JobY', propagate: false, wait: false, parameters: [[$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'MY_PARAM', value: "${env.SOME_VALUE}"]]`

Then in JobY on the "other side" you have:

```
environment {
    PARAM_FROM_PIPELINE = "${params.MY_PARAM}"
}
```

This gets the value of your parameter into an environment variable in JobY.

Depending on what the tasks are you could perform them in a batch (or sh) file by passing `PARAM_FROM_PIPELINE` like so:

```
stages {
    stage("Do Tasks") {
        steps {
            bat "mybatchfile.bat ${env.PARAM_FROM_PIPELINE}"
        }
    }
}
```

Finally in mybatchfile.bat you can read the value of `${env.PARAM_FROM_PIPELINE}` like so:

```
@ECHO OFF

SET PARAM_VAL=%1
ECHO PARAM VALUE IS: %PARAM_VAL%

IF %PARAM_VAL% = "A" (
  REM DO TASK1
) ELSE (
    IF %PARAM_VAL% = "B" (
        REM DO TASK2
    ) ELSE (
        REM DO TASK3
    )
)
```

If you don't want to encapsulate the if-else logic in a batch file you can use a `script {...}` block in your Jenkinsfile to use scripted pipeline.